# Why can't I install openssl on my Mac by homebrew?

Tags: macos, openssl, homebrew

I run the following code, which show that there are no openssl repo find in brew.

My Mac is macOS Big Sur 11.3.1

```
% brew install openssl
Updating Homebrew...
fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).
==> Updated Casks
Updated 1 cask.

Warning: No available formula or cask with the name "openssl".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
This formula was found in a tap:
homebrew/portable-ruby/portable-openssl
To install it, run:
  brew install homebrew/portable-ruby/portable-openssl
```

---

UPDATE

Seems that my brew can't install ccache either like the following. It is more of a brew issue?

```
brew install ccache
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following commands help

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/
rm -rf homebrew-core
git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core.git
```

Answer (score 0):

try this put it in terminal and run:

brew uninstall openssl; brew uninstall openssl; brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb

Comment: There is another error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
`brew extract` or `brew create` and `brew tap-new` to create a formula file in a tap on GitHub instead.: Invalid usage: Non-checksummed download of openssl formula file from an arbitrary URL is unsupported!  (UsageError)

Comment: i try this one and work perfectly:

brew uninstall openssl --ignore-dependencies
brew tap-new $USER/old-openssl
brew extract --version=1.0.2t openssl $USER/old-openssl
brew install openssl@1.0.2t

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master
```

^This should be the fix anytime you see the error "Could not resolve HEAD to a revision, as you may find at the bottom of the output when running "brew doctor"